# Assign "$Post->ID" to custom id

Tags: php, wordpress

So, for a post loop, `$post->ID` is used to get the post id's.

Is there a way to "change" it to a custom "id"?

**Here is what I mean by it:**

So, I have a page that is passed onto a template via ajax as following:

There is a first php template called "`first.php`".

In this file, I have a post loop which contains a button:

```
  $id = get_the_ID();   
  <?php echo '<button type="button" class="rh_show_image" data-post_id="' .$id. '">' ;?>
     <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rh_image', true); ?>  
  <?php echo '</button>';?>
```

This button has `data-post_id` which contains the post id. When it is clicked, then a `second.php` is loaded via ajax:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.rh_show_image').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rh_contact_form_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");          
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
            dataType: 'html',
            data: ({ action: 'rh_second_php', rhc_post_id: rh_contact_form_id}),
            success: function(data){
                  jQuery('#rh_iamge_' + rh_contact_form_id).html(data);                   
        },
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        alert("Error!");
        return false;
        }  
        }); 
 }); 
 });            
</script>
```

When the `second.php` is called, as you can see from the script above, the `post_id` of the post is saved and parsed onto the template `(data: ({ action: 'rh_second_php', rhc_post_id: rh_contact_form_id}),`)

Then in the `second.php`, I have the following:

```
 <!--Show title-->
 <?php echo get_the_title($_REQUEST['rhc_post_id']); ?>
 <!--Show image-->
 <div class="images">                                   
    <?php
        $I_will_call_you = callme_image();                  

         foreach ($I_will_call_you as $slideshowimage)
                {

                echo "<img src='{$slideshowimage}' />";
                }                               

    ?>
</div>
```

So, essentially, I am using `$_REQUEST['rhc_post_id']` instead of `$post->ID`

**Here is the problem**

In the `image` div from the second.php, it does not show any images because it does not recognized the `post id` from `$_REQUEST['rhc_post_id']`.

So, is there a way to make it `equal` between `$post->ID` and `$_REQUEST['rhc_post_id']`?

Something like this:   `$_REQUEST['rhc_post_id']` = `$post->ID`

Thanks guys!

**EDIT**: The `image` div works fine when it is placed with a post loop, instead via ajax. So, the code itself works fine.

**Edit 2:** Syntax in the second.php is fixed now

Comment: syntax errors on second.php

Comment: syntax fixed. Simple error while writing the question.

Comment: Then it'd be better if you posted your actual code

Comment: The code structures are the same. I simple replaced the words to make things simpler. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Looks very complicated structure , but can´t you just sent the post_id with your data ?? and also, need to see other parts of the code to answer exact answer